# How to remove an element from JSON object in Play Framework

Tags: java, json, playframework, jackson

In Play Framework we have the helper method `Json.toJson()` to generate `JsonNodes` from the request body or DB queries, but I don't know how to remove specific fields from the object after it has been generated.

Answer (score 2):

Play uses [FasterXML/jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) under the hood.

For example, let's say that you want to retrieve the payload from a request. You call request().body().asJson(), in your controller and you get a JsonNode.

A JsonNode doesn't have insertion capabilities but ObjectNode has.

**1. Creating an ObjectNode**(showing 2 common ways to do it):

**a.** Casting to ObjectNode

```
ObjectNode json = (ObjectNode) request().body().asJson();
```

**b.** Using an ObjectMapper(gives you more control like serialization features)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

//set serialization features in cases where you need them
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, false);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

ObjectNode json = mapper.createObjectNode();
```

[**2. Adding/removing elements**](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html) (linked the ObjectNode API so you can check all of the available methods)

```
json.remove("fieldName");
json.put("anotherFieldName", "yesWeCan")
    .put("canWeDoBoolean", true)
    .put("howAboutNumbers", 1234567890);
```

Don't forget to check the rest of the [documentation/tutorials](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) as jackson is a complex library and you might want to educate yourself on the subject.